# Accessing Node with React-native returns an unhandled promise rejection warning (id: 0)

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, axios

I have a test backend route,

```
router.get("/test", (req, res) => {
    console.log("it works!");

    return res.json({ msg: "Success from backend" });
});
```

And in my react-native component, I have a method:

```
export const registerUser = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/users/test");

    console.log("response received --> ", res.data);
};
```

I get the error:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed]
```

However, when I access `http://localhost:5000/api/users/test` through my browser, I get the expected response and behaviour.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I've even tried using the `react-native-axios` library instead of just `axios`, but I get the same error/warning. Also, I'm translating a functioning ReactJS app to React-native, so I'm positive my backend logic/syntax is configured and correct.

---

Edit

Full warning below:

[image: img]

---

Edit 2

Code for axios call:

```
try {
  console.log("trying");
  const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/users/test", {
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    }
  });

  console.log("got it"); // never reached
} catch (err) {
  console.log("oh no"); // this doesn't log either, oddly enough
  console.log(err);
}
```

Warning thrown:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed]
* client/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/core/whatwg-fetch.js:504:29 in onerror
* client/node_modules/event-target-shim/lib/event-target.js:172:43 in dispatchEvent
* client/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:580:29 in setReadyState
* client/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:394:25 in __didCompleteResponse
* client/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventEmitter.js:190:12 in emit
* client/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:366:47 in __callFunction
* client/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:106:26 in <unknown>
* client/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:314:10 in __guard
* client/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:105:17 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Using Postman or directly from browser works.. through React-native it doesn't

Comment: Didn't you get some error like CORS same-origin or so?

Comment: I looked specifically for that, and no -- that's not the error. Should I investigate accordingly as if it were?

Comment: Well, didn't you try to use fetch()? And compare results

Comment: Or maybe there is some 4xx HTTP return code

Comment: I just did and it is throwing the same error

Comment: Try to wrap that axios.get to try catch block and console log error from catch block

Comment: *How* did you "look specifically" for that? Because it sure looks like an SOP issue (which CORS is a way to fix) to me. From the error, it looks like your origin is port 19001, but the URL you're trying to access has port 5000. Those are different origins.

Comment: Try to install cors to server and add this `const cors = require('cors') and then app.use(cors())` hope you have `app` there

Comment: I tried, but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Can you send here what is the result after putting axios get function into try-catch block ?

Comment: Sure. I've added an Edit 2 to the OP

Comment: You got a server running on android? Otherwise you are  gonna need to specify your network ip.

Comment: That's an issue, you need to specify IP address of your computer where you have your API running. It would be `localhost` only if you have running your webserver on mobile

Answer (score 0):

The local development server cannot be accessed because the port has not yet been passed on by the `ADB`. Therefore, in this situation, you can map a `local server port` or use a `local IP address` to perform two tasks.

Obtain the port from the `ADB` by executing the following command at the terminal:

```
adb reverse tcp:5000 tcp:5000
```

OR

You can also use local IP. Shake the instrument or press and hold the menu button to open the developer menu. Click Open `Dev Settings`, and then click Next.  then tap `Debug server host & port for device`. Here you can enter your machine's local IP with port number `5000`

**Example**

```
192.168.1.50:5000
```